# Whether to use direct or directly

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I have learned that *direct* is both adjective and adverb. Then why we use **directly** in sentences. 
One of those sentences is-

> - The sun shone **directly** in my eyes.
> - You will report **directly** to the boss.

Can we replace *directly* with *direct*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.

> - The sun shone **direct** in my eyes.
> - You will report **direct** to the boss.

More examples ([M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/direct)):

> - The company sells its product **direct [=directly]** to customers on the streets.
> - It costs less if you buy it **direct [=directly]** from the manufacturer.